# Do Navigator pushNamed & pushReplacementNamed create zombie routes in memory?

Tags: flutter

Route A and Route B with buttons that can send to the other route when tapped (Route A with a button, Route B with a button on the bottombar).

Route A  --uses Navigator.pushNamed() to send to-->  Route B.

Route B --uses Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() to send to--> Route A.

And so on. Imagine to tap to obtain a loop.

Page A initState() is called multiple times but Page A dispose() is never called.

Does it mean that the memory is filling up of zombie Page A instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i understand.

when you `pushReplacementNamed` to new route, navigator will remove current route and based on [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacementNamed.html) said

> **The returned route will be pushed into the navigator.**

eg: we are from A to B .

- ****current Navigator is [ A, B ].****

then we `pushReplacementNamed` to A,  so it only replace route B from navigator and return all route before B (if exist) to current navigator.

- **current Navigator is [ A, A]**

then if you `pushNamed` from A again ,

- **then the Navigator will be [ A, A ,B].**

yes its not disposed.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to
```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/Messages",(Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```
It disposes the removed routes.